# Making textview dark?

Tags: java, android, textview

In my application I have a refresh function with a progressbar. The progressbar is on the textview which should be refreshed. The problem is: if there's much text in the textview, you don't see the progressbar so good. Is it possible to make the textview dark in onPreExcute/onPostExecute? I mean the darking like the Emulator does with the whole app after some time.

Has anyone an example for me?

Comment: You could put the ProgressBar somewhere else, or replace the refresh button (since there's not point having the user hit refresh again while it's spinning...)

Comment: yeah the refresh button gets disabled, but the textview white color is so "white" that it's not cool to try to see the progress bar if there is any text in the textview, donÄt know how to say my english is so bad :/ if you start an app in the emulator and you do nothing for a while, it will become grey, like a standby, and I want to achieve this grey just for the textview on refresh trough programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I don't know how to go about doing it like the Emulator does, but *in theory* something like this could work:

**UNTESTED CODE! I typed it in here.**

In the `onPreExecute()`, change the Background Color (`.setBackgroundColor`) for the TextView using this:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    .....

    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#74000000"));
}
```

And in the `onPostExecute()`, change it back to the original color:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    ....

    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
}
```

This is assuming that your original background color for the `TextView` is `#000000` (BLACK).

To see this effect in use, open up the Twitter app, go to any user's profile and see how they do it at the top of the screen where you see the user's profile picture (and banner if available) and sliding to the right, shows the description while fading the background. It looks like the background has *dimmed*.

Since I am using an Alpha channel in the `onPreExecute()` (`#74000000`), this will, (**again**), *in theory* produce a similar kinda effect.

If you would rather change the `TextView's` `textColor attribute`, change the `setBackgroundColor()` to this:

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

**NOTE:** As mentioned earlier, this is untested and just a theory on my part. But I suspect, this should set you in the right direction. You may have to fiddle with the values of course. They are just assumptions on my part based on what is in the OP.

Comment: "dimmed" is the word I searched^^ It works (: I have to play a little bit with the colors but all in all it works very well, thank you very much

Comment: @Phil: Lol.... I am glad I could help. For the record, _dimmed_ was kind of an afterthought. I put in it when I figured that it would make more sense in there. ;-)